# Cracking microphone

Tags: sound, headphones, microphone

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on ultrabook Honor MagicBook. The connector is soldered for headphones and microphone, I stick EarPods, on the test microphone in Steam,Discord heard a strong enough crackle. Twisted alsamixer(cleaned and microphone boosters, and included in one channel only) nothing helped. Inserted ordinary headphones to check the internal microphone in the laptop, just as bursting.

With this parallel is Windows 10,installed Realtek HD Audio, there are no problems with sound and micro.
How I can fix it?

System:
AMD® Ryzen 5 2500u

Info about sound:

[image]